# resolve internal DNS in linked docker containers

Tags: dns, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I build two base images via:

```
docker build --tag dw_web web/
docker build --tag dw_db db/
```

and start the db container via:

```
docker run -d --publish 3306:3306 --name dw_db_1 dw_db
```

When I start the web container via the following command I cannot ping my db container:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm --publish 8181:80 --link dw_db_1:dbsrv --name dw_web_1 dw_web /bin/bash

root@ccd4ad5f0ae4:/# env
HOSTNAME=ccd4ad5f0ae4
TERM=dumb
DBSRV_NAME=/dw_web_1/dbsrv
DBSRV_ENV_DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=
DBSRV_ENV_LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
DBSRV_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.3:3306
DBSRV_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DBSRV_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
DBSRV_PORT_3306_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:3306
DBSRV_PORT_3306_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DBSRV_ENV_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
DBSRV_ENV_TERM=dumb
_=/usr/bin/env
root@ccd4ad5f0ae4:/# 
root@ccd4ad5f0ae4:/# cat /etc/hosts 
172.17.0.4  ccd4ad5f0ae4
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  dbsrv d7814795da3c dw_db_1
root@ccd4ad5f0ae4:/# ping dbsrv
ping: unknown host dbsrv
root@ccd4ad5f0ae4:/# 
root@ccd4ad5f0ae4:/# ping -c 1 172.17.0.3
PING 172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.118 ms

--- 172.17.0.3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.118/0.118/0.118/0.000 ms
root@ccd4ad5f0ae4:/#
```

I've searched the web up and down but didn't find any hint to what I can look for. Both images are base don the ubuntu:1404 image and just install some packages via apt-get.

I've also tried to use `--dns` option without luck.

Any ideas I could have a look at?

thx,

Answer (score 0):

Find which DNS server you are using:

```
nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4
```

Then put the address to /etc/default/docker

```
docker_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8"
```

And restart docker

```
sudo restart docker
```

Comment: I neither use network-manager nor are the /etc/default/docker config changes working. I've already done this before I asked the question.